# Jquery click event not working after append method

Tags: jquery, html

So I have this button which adds a new row to the table, however my problem is that it does not listen to the `.new_participant_form` click event anymore after the append method has taken place.

http://jsfiddle.net/cTEFG/

Click Add New Entry then click on the Form name.

```
$('#add_new_participant').click(function() {


    var first_name = $('#f_name_participant').val();
    var last_name = $('#l_name_participant').val();
    var role = $('#new_participant_role option:selected').text();
    var email = $('#email_participant').val();


    $('#registered_participants').append('<tr><td><a href="#" class="new_participant_form">Participant Registration</a></td><td>'+first_name+ ' '+last_name+'</td><td>'+role+'</td><td>0% done</td></tr>');

    });

    $('.new_participant_form').click(function() {

        var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');

        var part_name = $td.eq(1).text();
        alert(part_name);

    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<table id="registered_participants" class="tablesorter">

<thead>
<tr> 
<th>Form</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Role</th>
<th>Progress </th>


</tr> 
</thead>


<tbody>
<tr> 
<td><a href="#" class="new_participant_form">Participant Registration</a></td>
<td>Smith Johnson</td>
<td>Parent</td>
<td>60% done</td>


</tr> 
</tbody>

</table>

<button id="add_new_participant"></span>Add New Entry</button>
```

Comment: The problem is that the event is only attached to the `new_participant_form` element that is already in the document. To make it work for elements you will add later as well, you can use event delegation, as dystroy has demonstrated, or attach the handler to each anchor before you insert it (the former is more efficient).

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$('#registered_participants').on('click', '.new_participant_form', function() {
```

So that the click is delegated to any element in `#registered_participants` having the class `new_participant_form`, even if it's added after you bound the event handler.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage regarding performance, if you use `$(document).on('click', '.new_participant_form', function() {});` ?

Comment: @basZero There's one, as jQuery would then have to handle all clicks and not just the one on the `#registered_participants` but to be fair this slowdown is so small it's irrelevant. It's mostly better to target the right element because it's cleaner.

Comment: Can i use on a new appended element have a same class name?

Answer (score 42):

The [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used to delegate events to elements, dynamically added or already present in the DOM:

```js
// STATIC-PARENT              on  EVENT    DYNAMIC-CHILD
$('#registered_participants').on('click', '.new_participant_form', function() {

  var $td = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
  var part_name = $td.eq(1).text();
  console.log( part_name );

});


$('#add_new_participant').click(function() {

  var first_name = $.trim( $('#f_name_participant').val() );
  var last_name  = $.trim( $('#l_name_participant').val() );
  var role       = $('#new_participant_role').val();
  var email      = $('#email_participant').val();
  
  if(!first_name && !last_name) return;

  $('#registered_participants').append('<tr><td><a href="#" class="new_participant_form">Participant Registration</a></td><td>' + first_name + ' ' + last_name + '</td><td>' + role + '</td><td>0% done</td></tr>');

});
```

```html
<table id="registered_participants" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Form</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Progress </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="new_participant_form">Participant Registration</a></td>
      <td>Smith Johnson</td>
      <td>Parent</td>
      <td>60% done</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" id="f_name_participant" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" id="l_name_participant" placeholder="Surname">
<select id="new_participant_role">
  <option>Parent</option>
  <option>Child</option>
</select>
<button id="add_new_participant">Add New Entry</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 15):

This problem could be solved as mentioned using the `.on` on jQuery 1.7+ versions.

Unfortunately, this didn't work within my code (and I have 1.11) so I used:

`$('body').delegate('.logout-link','click',function() {`

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

> As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded
>   by the .on() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already
>   discouraged. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most
>   effective means to use event delegation. More information on event
>   binding and delegation is in the .on() method. In general, these are
>   the equivalent templates for the two methods:

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

This comment might help others :) !

Answer (score 2):

** Here is the solution, that might help you **

```
// Changed to delegate() method to use delegation from the body

$("body").delegate("#boundOnPageLoaded", "click", function(){
   alert("Delegated Button Clicked")
});
```

Comment: The delegate() method was deprecated in version 3.0. So use the on() method instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", '.mylink', function(event) { 
alert("new link clicked!");});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 