# Click function not working in .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use click() as eventhandler and that event handler is not working you can see code below

```
    $('.ajax-close').click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hi');
        $( '.ajax-live-on' ).removeClass('ajax-live-on');
    });
```

I have used all the code to initialize the jquery no problem , all right. But this piece of code not working

Here is the jsBin link

http://jsbin.com/doxeravizo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: What is the problem? What do you mean by `not working`

Comment: that means not functioning

Comment: You forgot to include jquery library into your project

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420558/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-append-method

Comment: @muhaimin Is there still a problem preventing you to accept an answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The `$('.ajax-close')` collection doesn't contain the elements taking that class after the binding.

Change

```
$('.ajax-close').click(function( event ){
```

to

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.ajax-close', function( event ){
```

You should also move that binding outside of the loop, there's no reason to do it at every iteration.

Note also that in order to have your span clickable, it must have some content.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/menaxerile/1/) (I added the jQuery library to make the fiddle work)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that because you're using ajax, your `.ajax-close` is not created when the event listener is being created.

You're going to want to delegate your click function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax-close', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
    $('.ajax-live-on').removeClass('ajax-live-on');
});
```

[This article](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will help, but just for reference, this bit in particular:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to listen on the `click` event using a delegate, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax-close', function( event ){
    //your code
});
```

Another option might be to move your `click` listener inside the original `click` listener, which creates the "Close" button, while the reason the issue arises is that the `click` event on "ajax-close" is bound too soon (before the `<span>` is appended to the DOM even):

```
ajaxcontent.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( '.ajax-live' ).addClass('ajax-live-on');
    $( this ).after('<span class="ajax-close animated bounceInRight">Close</span>');
    $('.ajaxshow').append().load(ajaxUrl);
    $('.ajaxshow').addClass('animated bounceInUp');

    // Move this section here, which was previously located below  
    $('.ajax-close').click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hi');
        $( '.ajax-live' ).removeClass('ajax-live-on');
    });

});
```

Make sure to include some content in your "ajax-close" span to be able to click it like the word "Close".

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery library to your HTML head :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @dystroy it was a comment before it was an answer.

Comment: Well... It should not be an answer. As a comment it was fine of course.

Answer (score 0):

In your `given link` you are adding element `dynamically`, so need to use [event delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for dynamically created elements event binding.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax-close', function( event ){
  //your code
});
```