# Laravel blade : ajax replaced html portion don't interact with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm developing a Laravel project and I'm facing an issue with Ajax and Blade template.
In my scenario I have several tag (it can be divs, buttons or list items) with a class **ajaxaction** and an attribute **data-route**, like this:

```
      <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5106">
      <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5105">
      <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5104">
      <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5103">
      <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5102">
```

and a tag wrapping the content i will replace:

```
<div class="content">

</div>
```

In this page I have the *script* like this:

```
$('.ajaxaction').click(function () {
  ajaxURL = $(this).attr('data-route');
  $.get( ajaxURL, function(data) {
    $('.content').html(data);
  })
  .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('.content').html(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
  });
});
```

As I expect every time a tag is clicked the ajax send a GET request that return an HTML that replace the previous in content.
In some case the content replaced has a tag with class **ajaxaction** itself like this:

```
<div class="content">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5199">
    ...
</div>
```

But clicking on this tag do not send any ajax request.

Comment: in case you have a time, "event delegation" is a must read topic here

Comment: Use the .on() method to delegate the click event to (future) elements dynamically added to the DOM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420558/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-append-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mark as answered my question because the solution provided by @Chay22 and @Mehdi Alipour in their **comments** is exactly what I need to know.

[event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider this jquery ajax solution.

from your existing code.

```
    $('.ajaxaction').click(function () {
  ajaxURL = $(this).attr('data-route');
  $.get( ajaxURL, function(data) {
    $('.content').html(data);
  })
  .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('.content').html(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
  });
});

<div class="content">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="ajaxaction" data-route="http://localhost/webora/public/d/5199">
    ...
</div>
```

to this one. since you wrap your buttons already in your div. You create a script like this.

```
$('div.content').on(".ajaxaction","click",function(){
   var _btn = $(this);  
   $.ajax({
      url : _btn.data('route'),
      success : function(data){
          //your success data here

      },
      error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,thrownError){
        console.log(jqXHR); 
     } 
   })
});
```

don't use the `attr('data-xxxx')` because once they change the value of your `data-xxxx`, it will reflect to your code and run the code with the changes unlike with `data('xxxx')`, the initial value will still be the value even if they change it.

Comment: _As of jQuery 3.0,_ `.delegate()` _has been deprecated. It was superseded by the_ `.on()` _method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged._ http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: on that case , you can just update the function delegate to 'on' and still work ;) right ?