# click event on a html inserted by append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to use a html content inserted dynamically by `append(htmlString)` method in a page, the `click` event is not trigged. When I try to use the same html content normally, the `click` event is trigged.

```
$('#slc_field').change(function(event){
    $('#add_fields').removeClass("d-none");
    remove_link = "<a href='#' id="+this.value+" class='del_field text-danger' title='Remover item'> (x)</a>";
    html_field = " <div class='form-group col-md-4'>" +
                   "<label for='level_systemx'>Sistema de arranjo "+ remove_link +" </label> " +
                   "<textarea class='form-control' id='level_systemx' name='level_systemx' cols='250' rows='5'></textarea>" +
                  "</div>"
    $('#form_fields').append(html_field)
});

$('.del_field').click(function(event){
    $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).remove()

});
```

Is it possible to trigger the `click` event on a html inserted by the `append` method?

Comment: switch `on` and `click`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: event looks like it contains 'on' ?

Comment: do you have any console output? and can you add your html please?

Comment: I will edit the code to correct the syntax. But, no error outputs in console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery click event not working after append method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420558/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-append-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this also,

```
 $(document).on('click', '.del_field',function(event){
    $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('body').click('on', '.del_field', function(event){
    $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).remove()
});
```

Comment: When you Append anything dynamically , then you have to trigger event  within given Scope, either you can use document, body or any high level dom element

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for `click` event seems to be incorrect. You need to swap `click` keyword with that of `on`. The correct syntax should look like the one as below:

```
$('.del_field').on('click', function (event) {
    $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).remove()
});
```

Comment: Syntax is correct, your event is depend on dom element whether it is there or not at the time of event firing, best is always append with your scope