# Autodesk forge viewer table row click to isolate elements

Tags: javascript, html-table, autodesk-forge, forge, isolate

I am trying to create a dynamic table inside the viewer's page.
each row of the table represents an object from the model and has a couple of different parameters ( name, level, etc..)
I want to make a click event on each row, that isolates the element in the viewer's model.

I have created the table programmatically using js. (the table is created after pressing an external command button )

how can I add an event listener to a row click, that would isolate the element?

this is my code for creating the table after pressing the command button:

```js
var myTable = $('.my-table');
var myArr = rows; //matrix of object values

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)
    myTable.append("<tr id=" + i + ">" +
        " <td>" + myArr[i][0] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][1] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][2] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][3] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][4] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][5] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][6] + "</td>" +
        "<td id=" + "tt" + ">" + myArr[i][7] + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
const row = document.getElementById(`${i}`);
row.addEventListener('onClick', function(evt, item) { /// we are using a viewer api property to  isolate the 
    _this.viewer.isolate(_this.modelData.getIds(myArrNames[i][1], item[0]._model.label));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not a Forge issue but a JavaScript syntax and indent issue.

After re-indenting your code, you can see the codes for adding the click event is out of the for-loop, so you need to add the bracket pair to include the codes for adding the click event into the for-loop.

When defining for-loop in JavsScirpt without bracket `{` and `}`, it only takes the first line in the count.

In addition, there is no `onClick` event. When using `addEventListener`, the event name is `click`, not `onClick`.

```js
var myTable = $('.my-table');
var myArr = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]; //matrix of object values

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    myTable.append("<tr id=" + i + ">" +
        " <td>" + myArr[i][0] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][1] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][2] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][3] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][4] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][5] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][6] + "</td>" +
        "<td id=" + "tt" + ">" + myArr[i][7] + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");

        const row = document.getElementById(`${i}`);
        row.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { /// we are using a viewer api property to  isolate the 
            _this.viewer.isolate(_this.modelData.getIds(myArrNames[i][1], item[0]._model.label));
        
        });
}
```

To use `onClick`, it will become:

```js
const row = document.getElementById(`${i}`);
row.onClick = function(evt) { /// we are using a viewer api property to  isolate the 
    _this.viewer.isolate(_this.modelData.getIds(myArrNames[i][1], item[0]._model.label));

});
```

Lastly, why not just use jQuery only? The `jquey.on` can help bind events to dynamically created items, so that the click event will be delegated to any `tr` element in the table, even if it's added after you bound the event handler.

```js
var myTable = $('.my-table');
var myArr = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]; //matrix of object values

myTable.on('click', 'tr', function() {
    _this.viewer.isolate(_this.modelData.getIds(myArrNames[i][1], item[0]._model.label));
});

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    myTable.append("<tr id=" + i + ">" +
        " <td>" + myArr[i][0] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][1] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][2] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][3] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][4] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][5] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + myArr[i][6] + "</td>" +
        "<td id=" + "tt" + ">" + myArr[i][7] + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
}
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420578